# Comparing a list to a separate list with assigned tags

Tags: powershell

i've recently started with powershell but have not yet found my ways with it.

The issue I'm facing is the following:
I want to be able to supply a list of users.
The script has to check each user and compare it to a different file.
In the different file, there is a full list of predefined usernames with tags.
For example:

```
User1 Group1,Group2  
User2 Group2  
User3 Group 1,Group3
```

I then want the script to check for each user if it exists in the predefined list and if so, check what tag it has.
Then I want the script to output the tags the user has so it can assign it to a single or multiple groups.

Any tips?
Currently the script has hardcoded predefined user-to-group entries so a lot of time is wasted on checking each entry.

Sorry if this is improper use of stackoverflow, if it is, please forward me tips so I can learn.

Comment: if the file is a plain text file, use `Get-Content` to load the file into a $Var. then iterate thru the lines and parse the user name & group names. if the file is a CSV file, use `Import-CSV` and then iterate thru that. the user name will be in the `.UserColumnName` and the groups will be in the various `.GroupColumnName` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
$user = 'User3'
$output = Get-Content file.txt | Where { $_.StartsWith($user) } |
    Select-Object @{n='User';e={$user}},@{n='Tags';e={$_ -replace '^\S+\s+'}}

# Output the Complete Object with Properties
$output

# Output the User
$output.User

# Output the Tags Comma-Delimited
$output.Tags

# Output the Tags as an Array

$output.Tags -split ','
```

If you have a common delimiter between your data columns, you can do less manipulation.

`Select-Object` here uses a calculated properties (syntax `@{n=property;e={expression}}`).

`-replace` uses regex to match a string and then perform a replacement. `^\S+\s+` matches a string that begins with non-white space and any following white space. Since no replace string is provided, it is automatically replaced with empty string.